# Date difference by grouping column value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sorry if it seems easy. I want to do calculation in this way by using excel formula
inside the same Filename, take the startDate where memo="begin" and the endDate where memo="end" and make the difference in minute in duration.

I searched about groupby function but i can't found how to do this by fileName grouping

| Line | fileName | startDate | endDate | memo | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa.docx | 2020-12-07 04:30:00.000000 | 2020-12-07 04:31:00.000000 | begin |  |
| 2 | aa.docx | 2020-12-07 04:30:00.000000 | 2020-12-07 04:30:01.000000 | other |  |
| 3 | aa.docx | 2020-12-07 04:30:00.000000 | 2020-12-07 04:30:04.000000 | other |  |
| 4 | aa.docx | 2020-12-07 04:30:00.000000 | 2020-12-07 04:33:00.000000 | end | 3 |
| 5 | bb.docx | 2020-12-07 08:30:00.000000 | 2020-12-07 08:31:00.000000 | begin |  |
| 6 | bb.docx | 2020-12-07 08:30:00.000000 | 2020-12-07 08:30:01.000000 | other |  |
| 7 | bb.docx | 2020-12-07 08:30:00.000000 | 2020-12-07 08:30:04.000000 | other |  |
| 8 | bb.docx | 2020-12-07 08:30:00.000000 | 2020-12-07 08:34:00.000000 | end | 4 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
F2:  =IF($E2="end",$D2-LOOKUP(2,1/(($E1:$E$2="begin")*($B1:$B$2=$B2)),$C1:$C$2),"")
```

and fill down.

The `LOOKUP` function will return the latest preceeding "begin" for the given File name
*(assuming the dates are sorted in chronologic order)*

The results are in "excel" time (fractions of a day) and formatted as `[hh]:mm:ss`  If you want a decimal number representing minutes and fractions of a minute, format as `General` and multiply the result of the subtraction by `1440` *(number of minutes in a day)*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could look for "end" and then subtract the last seen "begin" startDate from it like this:

```
=IF([@memo]="end",([@endDate]-INDEX($C$2:C5,MAX(ROW($C$2:C5)*($E$2:E5="begin"))))*24*60,"")
```

The last seen begin is calculated by creating an INDEX from the the first startDate of the table to the current row and then taking the MAX row and multiplying it by the condition that memo = "begin".

[image: screenshot]

To have it also match the Filename, use this:

```
=IF([@memo]="end",([@endDate]-INDEX($C$2:C13,MAX(($B$2:B13=[@fileName])*ROW($C$2:C13)*($E$2:E13="begin")),))*24*60,"")
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! but, startDate/begin is not always the same than startDate/end

Comment: OK - I think I understand now.  I will edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I should precise that i can have more than two "other" so there is  not always 4 line per group.. This is why I want to group by fileName, or maybe it is possible de calculate dynamically the number of line ?

Comment: Ahh ok -by file name - just a sec

Comment: OK - in the last edit, it matches the filename.  There is no dependence on "other" - there could be 0, 4 or 1000's and it will still calculate.  However:  There is a dependence on sort order.  If the order of the rows is not chronological, then it will give a wrong result. If you need a formula that will allow for non chronological sorting, let me know. That will is possible, but will take some thinking.